# Make UI element to follow camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, menu, virtual-reality

I would like to make the menu follow the camera so when the user gazes at the menu, the menu could be triggered.

I'm setting the position of the menu with reference to the `FirstPersonCamera` which is the main camera as follows in my `Update` function,

```
menuCanvas.transform.position = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position 
                               +(FirstPersonCamera.transform.forward * 4);
```

Unfortunately, the menu is sticking to the camera center always and hence it is always triggered. How do I position the contextual menu properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. use a [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) in order to make the movement *smoother* (for far distance object moves faster, for shorter distance slower).

Then you could limit the target position not to the center of the display but allow an offset in each direction. A very simply example might look like

```
// how far to stay away fromt he center
public float offsetRadius = 0.3f;
public float distanceToHead = 4;

public Camera FirstPersonCamera;

// This is a value between 0 and 1 where
// 0 object never moves
// 1 object jumps to targetPosition immediately
// 0.5 e.g. object is placed in the middle between current and targetPosition every frame
// you can play around with this in the Inspector
[Range(0, 1)]
public float smoothFactor = 0.5f;

private void Update()
{
    // make the UI always face towards the camera
    transform.rotation = FirstPersonCamera.transform.rotation;

    var cameraCenter = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position + FirstPersonCamera.transform.forward * distanceToHead;

    var currentPos = transform.position;
    
    // in which direction from the center?
    var direction = currentPos - cameraCenter;

    // target is in the same direction but offsetRadius
    // from the center
    var targetPosition = cameraCenter + direction.normalized * offsetRadius;
    
    // finally interpolate towards this position
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, targetPosition, smoothFactor);
}
```

Ofcourse this is far from perfect but I hope it is a good starting point.

---

A moe complex/complete solution can e.g. found in the [HoloToolkit](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity): [`SphereBasedTagalong`](https://github.com/chinmaychinara91/HoloToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Utilities/Scripts/SphereBasedTagalong.cs) (any version before it was called `MixedRealityToolkit 2.x.x`)

> ```
> // Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> // Licensed under the MIT License. See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
>
> using UnityEngine;
>
> namespace HoloToolkit.Unity
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// A Tagalong that stays at a fixed distance from the camera and always
>     /// seeks to stay on the edge or inside a sphere that is straight in front of the camera.
>     /// </summary>
>     public class SphereBasedTagalong : MonoBehaviour
>     {
>         [Tooltip("Sphere radius.")]
>         public float SphereRadius = 1.0f;
>
>         [Tooltip("How fast the object will move to the target position.")]
>         public float MoveSpeed = 2.0f;
>
>         [Tooltip("When moving, use unscaled time. This is useful for games that have a pause mechanism or otherwise adjust the game timescale.")]
>         public bool UseUnscaledTime = true;
>
>         [Tooltip("Display the sphere in red wireframe for debugging purposes.")]
>         public bool DebugDisplaySphere = false;
>
>         [Tooltip("Display a small green cube where the target position is.")]
>         public bool DebugDisplayTargetPosition = false;
>
>         private Vector3 targetPosition;
>         private Vector3 optimalPosition;
>         private float initialDistanceToCamera;
>
>         void Start()
>         {
>             initialDistanceToCamera = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.position);
>         }
>
>         void Update()
>         {
>             optimalPosition = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * initialDistanceToCamera;
>
>             Vector3 offsetDir = this.transform.position - optimalPosition;
>             if (offsetDir.magnitude > SphereRadius)
>             {
>                 targetPosition = optimalPosition + offsetDir.normalized * SphereRadius;
>
>                 float deltaTime = UseUnscaledTime
>                     ? Time.unscaledDeltaTime
>                     : Time.deltaTime;
>
>                 this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(this.transform.position, targetPosition, MoveSpeed * deltaTime);
>             }
>         }
>
>         public void OnDrawGizmos()
>         {
>             if (Application.isPlaying == false) return;
>
>             Color oldColor = Gizmos.color;
>
>             if (DebugDisplaySphere)
>             {
>                 Gizmos.color = Color.red;
>                 Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(optimalPosition, SphereRadius);
>             }
>
>             if (DebugDisplayTargetPosition)
>             {
>                 Gizmos.color = Color.green;
>                 Gizmos.DrawCube(targetPosition, new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f));
>             }
>
>             Gizmos.color = oldColor;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I tried the first solution. It works well. However, it changes the scale of the UI element. and also it keeps the UI element to be at the center always but I want it to be lower so it can be triggered only when the user gazes down.

Comment: As said you will have to play around a bit with the values in the Inspector. There is nothing changing the scale of your panel .. it probably just got closer to the camera then desired. The second one is very powerful but also has some flaws ^^

Comment: the second one works :P but when the user rotates, the menu is not rotating. :(

Comment: I used  menuCanvas.transform.LookAt(FirstPersonCamera.transform); but it is flipped the opposite side.

Comment: @Roger The reason for this is that UI's forward always points **away** from the user not towards ;) For the rotation you either can implement it using `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, FirstPersonCamera.transform.rotation, someLerpFactor);` or you can go for another file from the HoloToolkit: [`Billboard`](https://github.com/IdanAizikNissim/HoloToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Utilities/Scripts/Billboard.cs)

Comment: is it possible to flip the canvas horizonally with lookAt? I tried to flip it by using `Vector3.right` but it does not flip properly

Comment: let me try that solution :)

Comment: I tried it but still, the canvas is not being flipped properly :(